# Http Call inside a concat and flatmap operator not working without subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to make a sequential http call in an existing code. I am using below code to trigger this http call,  but it only works when i use .subscribe for it. I tried using map, switchMap operators but nothing worked for me. Can someone throw light if using a .subscribe is correct and only way OR is there any other operator i can use to achieve this.

```
testEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.newsEnabled$.pipe(
    take(1),
    withLatestFrom(
      this.one$,
    ),
    switchMap(
      ([
        one,
      ]) =>
        this.dataPersistence.fetch(actionType.guest, {
          run: (
            action: Action & { request: guestReq },
            state: testState
          ) => {

            return concat(
              of(loading()),
              this.service.addTodo(req).pipe(
                tap({
                  next: () => {
                    console.log("firstlog")
                  }
                }),
                flatMap((response) =>
                  concat(
                    of(
                      processOne({
                        pone: response,
                      })
                    )

                  **//NEW change try to make http call** 

                    this.service.postupdate().pipe(
                      tap((resp) => { console.log(resp) }),
                      catchError((e) => { console.log(e) })
                    ) //   adding .subscribe() here the API call is happening, but when no subscribe it is not doing anything

                  **//NEW change try to make http call**

                    of(
                      processTwo({
                        ptwo: response,
                      })
                    )
                  )
                ),
                catchError((err) => {

                  console.log("error")
                }),
                finalize(() => {
                  //spinner close
                })
              )
            );
          }
        })
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

Comment: This is because you never actualy request the value of the observable. So it wil never be executed. Instead of your flapmap (that is deprecated) you should use forkjoin or combinelatest with possibly a mergemap inside (depending on what you want).